# Is the ground state the only eigenstate in atoms couple to radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, ground-state

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian of an atom  couple to radiation. If $\psi$ is eigenstate of the Hamiltonian  we have $i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = E \psi$ which give us $$\psi(t)=\psi(0)e^{-iEt/\hslash}$$

So the probability that of finding the system in this  state at time $t$ is 1.

Since atoms spontaneous radiate that means that the only eigenstate possible for   atoms is the ground state?

Answer (score 0):

If your Hamiltonian incorporates the photon field, then your eigenstate is a direct product of two Hilbert spaces. The atomic state ($\psi$) and the photonic state ($n$), $|\psi,n\rangle$.
Here $n$ represents the number of photons present in the field.

For simplicity we are considering monochromatic photons whose energy corresponds to the energy difference between excited state $|\psi\rangle = |e\rangle$ and the ground state $|\psi\rangle = |g\rangle$.

In this case, the state $|e,0\rangle$ is degenerate with $|g,1\rangle$. So any linear combination of the two is an eigenstate as well. So in a larger sense, your system is actually in an eigenstate if you consider the photons as well. Which if you don’t consider, you’ll have to understand that the spontaneous emission occurs due to some external factor perturbing the system.